# SSH file transfer between two PCs via a third one

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

I have two file storage boxes (synology aka Box1 and openmediavault aka Box 2) which are quite locked down and I only access them via SSH to read and write files. I now want to transfer files from Box1 to Box2 by doing SSH connections from PC3 (Windows 10) to Box1 and PC3 to Box2 and then transfer files from let's say 2 to 3 to 1.
The issue of course is that file storage boxes have tens of Tb and PC3 has little space so I cannot just transfer from 2 to 3 then 3 to 1. I need all connections to be aware of each other and to manage space used on PC3 for maximum throughput. How do I set this up?

Comment: Are you able to ssh to e.g. Box1 and then from there do a direct transfer to Box2? If not, `scp -3 Box1:/something Box2:/wherever` on PC3 might be the best option.

Comment: I do not want to originate any connections from Box1 and Box2. Don't know if I can but this is done within a big org setting and if something goes wrong I have no physical access to the boxes 1 and 2. So I do not want to change permissions, get shell access and run code on them.

Comment: Now scp is not strictly speaking the answer. Box 2 is Windows so my options are putty (so the command would start pscp -scp) or something like winscp. So one question is whether there is a drag and drop solution, like would winscp allow drag and drop between two hosts from an intermediary. But the central question is how to set buffer size on Box 2 for best file transfer speed? Any scp (which to me is interchangeable with ssh as far as file transfer goes) software for windows which dynamically tunes QoS for complex routing?